# Convert server response to valid object with js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have response from server that looks this way:

```
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"} 
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"} 
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}
```

Response comes in text format.

Parse JSON doesn't work because of "Unexpected token {"

Please help me to convert this into valid object

**UPDATE 1**

Output of

```
const arr = `[${res.replaceAll('\n', ',')}]`
```

Is

```
[{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}, 
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}, 
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"},]
```

Looks like a problem is in the last comma, when I'm copying res data manually, it doesn't happen.

**UPDATE 2**

In addition server response included invisible empty lines, that I didn't noticed and trim() fixed it

Comment: Why do you have such a strange response? Can you fix the backend?

Comment: I will request to fix it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should try to fix the problem on the server side. Only if that's not possible, you should fix the problem on the client side.

Your actual input text seems to be

```
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}
```

with an empty line at the end.

You can trim the string (remove all whitespaces around it), replace the linebreaks with separators and wrap it all in square brackets. Then you can parse it as JSON:

```
JSON.parse(`[${res.trim().replaceAll('\n', ',')}]`)
```

That gives you an array of objects and you can work with it as usual.

Example

```js
const res = `{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}
{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}`;

const arr = JSON.parse(`[${res.trim().replaceAll('\n', ',')}]`);
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[1].value2);
```

Comment: Thanks @jabaa, that supposed to work.. But by some reason it doesn't. If I copy response from browser's console - it works. When I'm passing it as variable, i'm getting this error:  Unexpected token ] in JSON

Comment: @DmitryMind Can you log the actual response text with `console.log(res)` and the result of `\`[${res.replaceAll('\n', ',')}]\`` before parsing it and add it to your question?

Comment: added result of `[${res.replaceAll('\n', ',')}]`

Comment: @DmitryMind You forgot an empty line in your question. I fixed my code. You should update your question to clarify the actual problem.

Comment: now it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DmitryMind I added it to my answer. Your input text actually has 4 lines. 3 lines contain an object and one line is empty. `replaceAll` added an separator (comma) at the end. That's not allowed in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I did not understand the question so here's a better answer:

```js
const res = `{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}\n{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}\n{"value1":1,"value2":45,"value3":"x"}`;

const resArray = res.split("\n");

let realOutputArray = [];

resArray.forEach(res => {
    
    let inputObject = JSON.parse(res);

    let outputArray1 = [];

    // loop through all the values in the object
    for (const key in inputObject) {

        // add the new value to the array
        outputArray1.push(inputObject[key]);
    }
    
    realOutputArray.push(outputArray1);
});



console.log(realOutputArray); // is should output "[ [1, 2, 3, ...], [1, 2, 3, ...], ...]"
```

Comment: I did just now!

Comment: now the real fix

Comment: because i thought they wanted it to be an array